# Eclipse Graphical Layout Window Metrics returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom View that needs the screen resolution to do some math... It needs to scale some text so that it always fits within a space in the view. So I need to know the size of the view.

The code below works fine on the device and emulator. But it bombs out in the Eclipse Graphical Layout preview with a NullPointerException. It seems the WindowManager does not work in the Eclipse preview. So now, I am checking the value and hard coding it when it's not reasonable... But it also means I need to keep editing the number to test different screen sizes.

There must be a better way. Anyone?

Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {

    Context context=this.getContext().getApplicationContext();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int displayWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int displayHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    if (!(displayWidth > 0))
        displayWidth = 720;

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics(). Getting it from the window manager might be a little too "low-level" for eclipse to deal with nicely.

I would also suggest that you use the measure specs rather than the displaymetrics unless you have permission to draw outside of your view/activity bounds, the actual space you are trying to fit in is always passed into onMeasure WidthSpec/HeightSpec..